# Dependence of elasticity on temperature and degree of vulcanization of typical commercial rubber band

Tags: thermodynamics, polymers, rubber

I am doing a school experiment that tries to find how the elasticity of rubber band depends on temperature.
From all the research I have done, theory suggests stress to increase linearly with temperature at a given strain, this I understand can be derived by modeling rubber as ideal chains and consider entropic force.
[image]

However, my data seems to show the opposite:
[image]

Now I have digged up the paper that gave the first graph, I believe the method they used is the same as mine (stretching the rubber in water bath), so the only key difference has to be the material we used. The sample they claimed to use is 'eight part sulfur and one hundred parts pale crepe, vulcanized at 147 C, for 180 min', whereas the rubber band I used is just one of those really standard rubber band you can buy in a stationary store (link for store: https://item.jd.com/5326713.html#none) (Another link for a typical commercial rubber band brand: [https://www.amazon.com/Rubber-Bands-Band-Depot-Pound/dp/B082WMN7PF/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?keywords=rubber%2Bbands&qid=1704758500&sr=8-2-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082WMN7PF) ). The store's webpage contains no detail about the exact material of the band, and I couldn't find any articles showing the exact material or degree of vulcanization of ANY typical rubber band. Now my current explanation for my opposite trend is that in order to increase performance and strength, commercial rubber band are highly vulcanized and otherwise treated, causing severe steric hindrance, so that the degree of tangling and entropy increase in contracting becomes insignificant, so that the mechanism for rubber band contraction are now like most other material.

So what I would appreciate is any rough estimate of the degree of vulcanization of a typical rubber band, approximately how different is that compared to the 8% sample, any link that might lead to the detailed manufacturing of a specific rubber band brand, or critisism / confirmation of my current ideas.

Comment: This looks like a wild goose chase, although I'm no expert on vulcanization. *It might* help to look for a similar product in another website, maybe one that is more accessible to the anglophone audience at chem SE, or to provide a link to a translated page.

Comment: If I interpret this correctly strain is how far you stretched the band, and stress is the force you needed to apply. I'm surprised the experiment was performed like this (constant strain). I would think it'd be easier to apply a constant stress (say by hanging a weight from the band) and measure the strain response over T. How did you do the experiment?

Comment: Perhaps make your own rubber test samples, so they can be standardized. Vulcanization is fairly straightforward: https://www.theslingshotforum.com/threads/homemade-rubber-vulcanisation-experiment.30091/. You might also test artificial rubbers, such as used in inner tubes.

Comment: @BuckThorn, I have provided a link from amazon, what I did is that I first did force over extension test at a fixed temperature, so I initially get a bunch of stress over force over extension graph at different temperature, but because I chose a fixed set of extension each time I do the experiment, I could make the force over temperature graph I showed here.

Comment: One thing that stands out when comparing the graphs is that the strain in yours was much greater, even if the forces aren't, for instance 175% vs 22% at 2 kg/cm2. This suggests you used a much softer rubber band (smaller force constant), or that the units in your plot are different, or that you calculated % extension some other way. Would be good if you look into this. // As for commerical rubber band manufacturing info (vulcanization recipe) that is probably a trade secret. You might also consult diy sites like  DrMoishe Pippik suggested.